# How do I convert a date to a HTTP-formatted date in .Net / C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

How does one convert a .Net DateTime into a valid HTTP-formatted date string?

Answer (score 91):

Dates can be converted to HTTP valid dates (RFC 1123) by using the "r" format string in .Net. HTTP dates need to be GMT / not offset - this can be done using the ToUniversalTime() method.

So, in C# for example:

```
string HttpDate = SomeDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");
```

Right now, that produces HttpDate = "Sat, 16 Aug 2008 10:38:39 GMT"

See [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for a list of .Net standard date & time format strings.

See [Protocol Parameters](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html) for the HTTP date specification, and background to other valid (but dated) RFC types for HTTP dates.

Comment: I tried this without adding `.ToUniversalTime()` and just wanted to comment that it *is* necessary. Simply using `.ToString("r")` will *format* the datetime with `GMT` specified, but it won't truly be in UTC.

Comment: @JYelton this is not correct in general. It only is necessary if you are not working with UTC dates (There should be a good reson if you do not). A date that is already UTC does not need `.toUniversalTime()`.